# powershell: comment based help

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've created a small script to test creating my own help based powershell and i received error:

> Get-Help : Cannot find Help for topic ".\testHelp.ps1". At line:49
>   char:15
>   +       Get-Help <<<<  @PSBoundParameters | more
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-Help], HelpNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HelpNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand

Heres the test script:

```
<#
SYNOPSIS
retrieive a list of services from local and remote machines 
.DESCRIPTION
Retrieive services from local and remote machines and reports the following fields
.PARAMETER  Servers 
The Get-Service cmdlet gets objects that represent the services on a local computer or on a remote computer.
.EXAMPLE
PS C:\> Get-Something 'One value' 32
#>
param($computername="localhost")
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $computername
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `.` in front of `.SYNOPSIS`.  Also your help says the parameter is called `Servers` but the param block says `$computername`.  PowerShell is pretty finicky about the help formatting being just right although I don't think it validates parameter names.  :-)

The result is:

```
PS> Get-Content .\FuncHelp.ps1
<#
.SYNOPSIS
retrieive a list of services from local and remote machines 
.DESCRIPTION
Retrieive services from local and remote machines and reports the following fields
.PARAMETER  Servers 
The Get-Service cmdlet gets objects that represent the services on a local computer or on a remote computer.
.EXAMPLE
PS C:\> Get-Something 'One value' 32
#>
param($computername="localhost")
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $computername


PS> .\FuncHelp.ps1 -?

NAME
    C:\Users\hillr\FuncHelp.ps1

SYNOPSIS
    retrieive a list of services from local and remote machines


SYNTAX
    C:\Users\hillr\FuncHelp.ps1 [[-computername] <Object>] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Retrieive services from local and remote machines and reports the following fields


RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help C:\Users\hillr\FuncHelp.ps1 -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help C:\Users\hillr\FuncHelp.ps1 -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help C:\Users\hillr\FuncHelp.ps1 -full".
```

Comment: Ive put a . in front and still same issue

Comment: Is Get-Help being proxied?  Try running to `Get-Command Get-Help | Format-List *` to see which module `Get-Help` is coming from.

Comment: the powershell script was also running through a UNC path which the security didnt like. Copied locally and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free Quest editor called [PowerGui](http://powergui.org/index.jspa). You've got the a snippet (CTRL+I) for functions with advanced help. It gives you all the advanced help keywords as you can find in [about_Comment_Based_Help](http://technet.microsoft.com/us-us/library/dd819489.aspx)

You can put `<# #>` befor your function or inside, but be careful with special characters inside the help it cause me some errors when copy/pasting some examples from the net or PDF documents.